# Nice (and rather short) applications of module theory for a book chapter

Tags: soft-question, modules

I am currently preparing a second edition of my introductory book on module theory, and for editorial reasons, I need to add 21 pages (the format of the pages is something like the new editions of Bourbaki), including few exercises.

The book aims to an audience of 4th year student, having a background in  basic algebra (linear algebra over a field, a bit of group theory, basic ring theory).

For the moment, the book covers the following topics: modules, submodules, exact sequences, quotient modules, cyclic modules, definitions and basic properties of noetherian, free, projective, stably free modules, localisation, local characterization of projective modules, tensor product over a commutative ring, algebras and  graded tensor product of algebras, tensor algebra, exterior algebra, exterior powers, fg modules over a PID, fg modules over a Dedekind domain, and Quillen Suslin Theorem (every finitely generated module over a polynomial ring is free).

The purpose of my book is to be a first course in module theory, so the last two topics are really the maximal level of difficulty I want to reach.

The first idea coming to my mind is to add a new chapter, but i'm lacking of ideas considering the choice of the topic. I'm pretty sure I don't want to talk about representation theory, since 21 pages is too short to present something convincing.

I thought about adding a chapter on skew fields (since most of the theorems involve module theory and tensor products), but without any real application of skew fields or Brauer groups, it might feel that this chapter would pop out of nowhere (plus the fact that I left the proofs of Wedderburn theorem and Skolem Noether as exercices in the chapter on algebras).

**Question.** Do you have any idea of a suitable topic for a new chapter ?

Comment: If not already somehow inter-weaved in the other chapters, and I know you said you did not want to introduce representation theory because you couldn't do it justice; but still, perhaps you could either add a gentle introduction to algebraic geometry (just introduce the zariski top. and explain the correspondence between alg. and geom.) or homological algebra; or add just an overview of the different most important topics with suggestions to further study. I often find this very helpful. Thus that chapter would need to be less formal, and more inspirational.

Comment: Maybe adding some property of the category of modules? like an abelian category with some nice properties with regard to direct limits?